# Google Analytics (gtag.js) track button click

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I was using Legacy Analytics, my website is all in one page, so I never change the link, I need to track button clicks, on legacy I was using:

```
onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/index#aboutus']);"
```

Which works fine, but on gtag.js I can't find how to send this to Google without needing to create things on analytics admin panel.

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with: gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', {'page_path': '/new-page.html'});